# How to iterate a Process reading data from CSV using Windows Command Prompt

Tags: batch-file, csv, cmd

I have a data_config csv which is having data as shown below.

username1,password1

username2,password2

username3,password2

The number of rows is dynamic in nature and may vary.

Now my process starts :

1. I want to extract the username and password from line 1 and input that to a CSV file called start.csv.(Start.csv should contain only one row : username and password)
2. with this start.csv, I have to trigger an ANT build.
3. After this ANT build, I have to delete the contents in the start.csv

And do the same steps are above for all the username and password.

Can anyone please help me with the CMD code for this script?? Any help is much appreciated.

Adding my code:

```
@SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo off

for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%f in (C:\DemoTest\demo.csv) do (
echo %%f,%%g,%%h >"test.csv"
CALL Start
)
goto :eof
:Start
cd D:\New folder\New folder\apache-jmeter-2.11\apache-jmeter-2.11\extras
D:
ant
CALL Start1
goto :eof

:Start1
set SAVESTAMP=%DATE:/=-%@%TIME::=-%
set SAVESTAMP=%SAVESTAMP: =%
echo %SAVESTAMP%
cd C:\DemoTest
move Test.html C:\DemoTest\Result
move Test.jtl C:\DemoTest\Result
cd Result
rename "Test.html" "%SAVESTAMP%.html"
rename "Test.jtl" "%SAVESTAMP%.jtl"
goto :eof
```

Comment: You can read a file with a `for /f` loop. You can output to a csv file using `>` or `>>` (overwrite or append). Please try to solve the problem before asking a question here.

Comment: I got the logic, but the problem is after the first ant build none of the remaining lines are executed.

Comment: for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%f in (C:\DemoTest\demo.csv) do (
  echo %%f,%%g,%%h >"test.csv"
  CALL Start
  )
  goto :eof
:Start
cd D:\New folder\New folder\apache-jmeter-2.11\apache-jmeter-2.11\extras
D:
ant
CALL Start1
goto :eof

:Start1
set SAVESTAMP=%DATE:/=-%@%TIME::=-%
set SAVESTAMP=%SAVESTAMP: =%
echo %SAVESTAMP%
cd C:\DemoTest
move Test.html C:\DemoTest\Result
move Test.jtl C:\DemoTest\Result
cd Result
rename "Test.html" "%SAVESTAMP%.html"
rename "Test.jtl" "%SAVESTAMP%.jtl"
goto :eof

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (data_config.csv) do (
    >start.csv echo %%a
    call ant
)
del start.csv
```

Comment: for mulitple data in data config, the ant function is not iterating. Its executing only one time

Comment: How are you launching ant?  Are you using the call keyword?